# Where to connect an external power source for an Arduino motor driver shield to?

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I have a BYJ48 stepper motor and an ULN2003A motor driver shield shield.

In many tutorials I read:

> do not to draw current from the 5V on the Arduino rail, but use an
>   external power source, since the motor can draw quite some current

Which of these options to they mean by this?

> Connect an external power adapter to the Arduino and connect the
>   ULN2003A board to the Vin pin and GND on the Arduino

or

> Connect the motor shield itself to an external power adapter and connect it to the + and - pin on the motor shield

or perhaps both are valid solutions?

The board I use is [this one](https://www.ebay.nl/itm/5V-4-Phase-Geared-Stepper-Motor-with-ULN2003A-Driver-Board-28BYJ-48-Arduino/121433812858).

[image]

Comment: Link to the product you refer to?

Comment: https://www.ebay.nl/itm/5V-4-Phase-Geared-Stepper-Motor-with-ULN2003A-Driver-Board-28BYJ-48-Arduino/121433812858 I added it to the my question as well

Comment: You are missing a connection from the green wire to the Arduino GND.

Comment: I don't see the schematic for the motor driver.

Comment: @BasvanDijk where did you get your "external 5V power supply"? did you make it?

Comment: @alcor bought it from https://arduino-tutorials.net/r/ZsECKh 

I also made a tutorial about this motor with the power from an external power supply https://arduino-tutorials.net/tutorial/control-28byj-48-stepper-with-uln2003-driver-with-arduino

Comment: thanks, @BasvanDijk! I didn't know you had that great site. I was looking for something prettier than an external 5v source like that, but maybe I'm too spoiled :P thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Prevent the motor drawing its power from the micro-controller board.
2. Make sure that all the grounds are connected but avoiding motor current return through the micro-controller board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh0eDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A good wiring configuration. The heavy wires carry the motor current.*

Note that there is one ground connection between the micro-controller and the motor system. The return current for the 12 V supply does not pass through the micro-controller board.

Comment: Ok, what I have now is that the Arduino powered via the USB connection. The motor shield is complete independent powered with a 5V adapter. As shown on the eBay picture, there is a + and - pin on the driver board. This is where I connected the external power supply to. I did not connect the ground of the Arduino with the - pin in any way as shown in the picture.

Comment: And? Does it work or not? You need to connect the GND/- as I have shown for correct operation, otherwise there is no return path from the micro outputs 0 to 4.

Comment: Yeah it does work, but I still have my question. Since another option is to connect the external power supply directly in my Arduino and connect the motordriver + and - pin to the Vin and GND on the Arduino

Comment: Read my answer again. I explained why not to do that twice.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood "Prevent the motor drawing its power from the micro-controller board." I thought you referred to the USB provided 5V. For 12V I understand, but my motor is powered by 5V which the Arduino should be able to handle. This made me think I could power the Arduino as well as the motor on the external power supply.

Comment: That will be OK if the Arduino GND/- and stepper '-' are connected only at the power supply.